# Is there a file with system log?

Tags: filesystem, log

In Ubuntu there's a program called **System log**, with log of system and all that you do with Ubuntu. 
I would ask if would be possible create a file.txt that refresh automatically with log from 'System log", this file should refresh in every new log.
Bye,
Mattew.

Comment: The program "System Log" uses various log files that are found in your computer's `/var/log/`directory. You can explore that directory to see what system logs are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's rather the other way around.

That program just reads the informations from the text files in your `/var/log` directory...

Just look directly at those files and there you are! :)

Comment: Can I join inside it from terminam with: sudo cd /var/log and then use nano for open file inside /var/log?

Comment: Yes :) But for a lot of them you do not even need `sudo` (and, in fact, I advice that you do not use it).

Comment: Ok thanks, I assegnate your answer like better answer :D